# Bash script answer interactive prompts

Tags: bash

I want to create a script which i will use to generate some reports, but to do that i have to answer few questions, which being asked by other script i run.

The answers can be yes, no, for some questions i need to select 1,2 or 3, i some cases i need "Press [Enter] to continue:"...
So my questions how to do it in the best way?

This is my script as of now (and it is not working it is getting stopped on second question which i need to answer as Y)
the order of the answers is:
yes/yes/yes/ENTER/2/3/1/no/no/yes

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE ; do
        ssh $LINE <<"EOF"
                echo "$HOSTNAME"
                        printf '\Y \nY \nY \n \n2 \n3 \n1 \nN \nN \nY' |/tmp/script.sh
                done
EOF
done < file1 >> /tmp/result.log
```

ok now i getting issue in stage where i need to select 2/3/1 it is not answering 2 see example in log...

```
Choose the Veritas enterprise product family:
     1@)  NetBackup Family
     2@)  Storage Foundation and HA Solutions / InfoScale Solutions

Choose your option: [1-2,q] (1)@ Invalid input. Re-enter.
Choose your option: [1-2,q] (1)@
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use `expect`.

Comment: As others have commented you need tools like [tag:expect] for this if you want to do it in a programmable way. Expect uses [tag:tcl] which is another language. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: From the code above it seems you are trying to run a remote interactive command over SSH but non-interactively. There is a tool called `expect` that is designed specifically for this.

Comment: If you can't modify the second script "script.sh", indeed, you must absolutely use a command like expect, it is intended for this use.

Comment: Is it failing to answer the first prompt because you input `\Y<space>` instead of `Y`?

Comment: so to use expect i need to crate script with exact questions ad answers? e.g expext "Choose the Veritas enterprise product family: 1) NetBackup Family 2) Storage Foundation and HA Solutions / InfoScale Solutions" send --"2\r"

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the newlines explicitly to your script.

```
printf 'Y\nY\nY\n\n2\n3\n1\nn\nn\nY\n' | /tmp/script.sh
```

This assumes `Y` corresponds to "yes" and `n` corresponds to "no". You can also have `printf` loop over arguments, to cut down on the repetition of `\n`.

```
printf '%s\n' Y Y Y "" 2 3 1 n n Y | /tmp/script.sh
```

The empty string corresponds to pressing enter without any other input.